# How do you edit a role permission in discord.py?

Tags: permissions, arguments, discord.py, roles

I wrote a little Python Script which should give the "Administrator" permission to a certain role, just to try how role editing works. This is my code:

```py
 @bot.command()
 async def EditRoleTest(ctx):
     await ctx.guild.roles[1].edit("permissions(administrator)")
```

But as soon as I try to run it, the following error occurs:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: 
Command raised an exception: 
TypeError: edit() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

So how do I pass the argument that I want to add the permission administrator?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When editing a role you must pass a `discord.Permissions` instance as a keyword-only argument

```py
role = ctx.guild.roles[1] # Or another role object
perms = discord.Permissions(administrator=True)
await role.edit(permissions=perms)
```

#### Reference:

- [`Role.edit`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Role.edit)
- [`discord.Permissions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Permissions)